# Using the .split() function based on conditions?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, split

How would you be able to use the .split() function based on conditions?

Lets say I have the raw data:

```
Apples,Oranges,Strawberries Green beans,Tomatoes,Broccoli
```

My intended result is:

```
['Apples','Oranges','Strawberries','Green beans','Tomatoes','Brocolli']
```

Would it be able to have it split at commas and if there is a space and a capital letter following it?

Comment: Use `re.split` for this, for each capital letters.

Comment: @aIKid: Put answers in answers, not comments.

Comment: @EthanFurman Ha ha. Me don't know regex much, i'll leave it to you guys regex experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal interpretation of what you asked for, using `re.split`:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'\s(?=[A-Z])|,')
pat.split(my_str)
```

This is more simply done, in your case:

```
pat = re.compile(r'.(?=[A-Z])')
```

Basically, split on any character that is followed by a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex will make the code simpler than a complicated split statement.

```
import re
...
re.findall(", [A-Z]",data)
```

Note you asked for a split for a command, space, capital, but in your example there are no spaces after commas.

Comment: `re.findall(", [A-Z]",data)`?   That doesn't seem like it's going to do very much.

Comment: How exactly would I use this?

Comment: Try @roippi's solution, it's better.